# Dynamically swap multiple rows with database columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

First let me start by saying that I've done intensive research before asking here. I have a table `datatable` that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id | year | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec |
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | 2015 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 101 | 265 | 357 | 358 | 330 | 402 | 528 | 528 |
|  2 | 2016 | 602 | 837 | 854 | 723 | 802 | 943 | 689 | 771 | 595 | 487 | 647 | 488 |
|  3 | 2017 | 553 | 556 | 598 | 518 | 632 | 696 | 522 | 634 | 562 | 379 | 542 | 448 |
|  4 | 2018 | 483 | 378 | 397 | 289 | 283 | 277 | 432 | 379 | 260 | 305 | 286 | 199 |
|  5 | 2019 | 353 | 346 | 418 | 402 | 430 | 321 | 476 | 494 | 412 | 499 | 469 | 353 |
|  6 | 2020 | 363 | 422 | 191 |   0 |  42 | 253 | 333 | 368 | 389 | 387 | 329 | 273 |
|  7 | 2021 | 276 | 254 | 356 | 352 | 324 | 291 | 325 | 376 | 355 | 384 | 326 | 265 |
|  8 | 2022 | 312 | 321 | 447 | 414 | 523 | 556 | 719 | 888 | 501 | 484 | 619 | 174 |
|  9 | 2023 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

and I need a query to make my columns (jan to dec) into rows of a `months` column and the `year` rows into separate columns. The result should basically look like this:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| months | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| jan    |    0 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| feb    |    0 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| mar    |    0 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| apr    |    0 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| may    |  101 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| jun    |  265 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| jul    |  357 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| aug    |  358 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| sep    |  330 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| oct    |  402 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| nov    |  528 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
| dec    |  528 | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  | ###  |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

`###` is the corresponding mapping from the previous table. Since the original table can have `n` rows, the new table must evaluate its columns dynamically.

There are many resources on the web on how to do this dynamically, however they all assume only *one* key-value relationship must be pivoted, which is not the case here (I need every month). I managed to put together a query for `jan`:

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ''',
      year,
      ''' then jan else NULL end) AS `',
      year,
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  datatable;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, '
                  FROM datatable
                   GROUP BY id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

The above query yields this result:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| id | 2015  | 2016  | 2017  | 2018  | 2019  | 2020  | 2021  | 2022  | 2023 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | 0     | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 2  | NULL  | 602   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 3  | NULL  | NULL  | 553   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 4  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 483   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 5  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 353   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 6  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 363   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
| 7  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 276   | NULL  | NULL |
| 8  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 312   | NULL |
| 9  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 0    |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

This is unfortunately as far as I got after spending 10 hours today. I can't seem to figure out how to include the other months and aggregate the results.

I would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction, or simply knowing whether this is even possible at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by reviewing other [pivot-table] Q+A

Comment: And don't include `id` in the output.